# The regex pattern for the following string?

Tags: python, regex

What is the regex pattern for the following string:

```
hi firstName lastName 27 Jun 2017
```

There should be 3 fields identified in the string: priority, name and date. So far, I have the following regex:

```
^(\w+)\s+(.*?)\s+
```

It identifies priority but not the full name. My regex identifies up to the *firstName*, not including the *lastName*.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by priority? I don't see that in your example.

Comment: @James "hi" is "high", maybe?

Comment: Yes. hi is high

Comment: Need some explanation here. Is "first" = priority? And name is a single string without spaces?

Comment: My regex identifies priority and firstName. Not lastName. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex does not extract a full name because `\s+(.*?)\s+` part matches 1 or more whitespaces, and then matches and captures any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible up to the first 1+ whitespaces. These whitespaces are found after `firstName`, as there are no more obligatory atoms to match.

You may use

```
^(?P<priority>\w+)\s+(?P<name>.*?)\s+(?P<date>\d.*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VP1NRP/1/)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string (implicit if `re.match` is used)
- `(?P<priority>\w+)` - Group "priority": 1+ word chars
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
- `(?P<name>.*?)` - Group "name": any 0+  chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
- `(?P<date>\d.*)` - Group "date": a digit and then the rest of the line.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/1WJ9W8):

```
import re
rx = r"(?P<priority>\w+)\s+(?P<name>.*?)\s+(?P<date>\d.*)"
s = "hi firstName lastName 27 Jun 2017"
m = re.match(rx, s)
if m:
    print(m.group("priority")) # => hi
    print(m.group("name"))     # => firstName lastName
    print(m.group("date"))     # => 27 Jun 2017
```

Comment: @JonClements: Yes, [`{'priority': 'hi', 'date': '27 Jun 2017', 'name': 'firstName lastName'}`](https://ideone.com/ERRMdZ) looks vivid.

Comment: Just saying since you bothered to name the groups :)

Comment: Done. Thanks again @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.findall()`:

```
import re
s = "hello John Someone 27 June 2017"
name = re.findall("\w+[a-zA-Z]+", s)[1:-1]
priority = re.findall("^\w+", s)[0]
date = re.findall("\d+\s\w+\s\d+", s)[0]
print(name)
print(priority)
print(date)
```

Output:

```
['John', 'Someone']
'hello'
'27 June 2017'
```